# How to include jssor in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jssor

I'm trying to include `jssor` in `angularjs`, but it probably fails as the jssor is initialized before angularjs, and thus the `ng-repeat` elements cannot be resolved properly.

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <div u="slides">
    <!-- The static images would work -->
    <!--            <div><img u="image" src="static/myimg1.jpg"/></div> -->
    <!--            <div><img u="image" src="static/myimg2.jpg"/></div> -->
        <div ng-repeat="products in bags">
            <div ng-repeat="picture in bag.pictures">
                <img u="image" src="{{picture.url}}"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
    ...
    </style>
 <script>jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');</script>
</div>

<script src="js/jssor.slider.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jssor_slider1_starter = function(containerId) {
        var options = {
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,
                $ChanceToShow: 2
            },
            $FillMode: 1
        };
        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
    };
</script>
```

**Question**: what might be wrong here? And especially: how could I delay the initialization of the full jssor div *after* angularjs is loaded?

Console error (before angularjs is loaded):

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/%7B%7Bpicture.url%7D%7D"
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `jssor` initialization code in some Angular controller, and use `$timeout` to wait for `ng-repeat` to finish rendering the view:

```
<div id="slider1_container">
    <div u="slides" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div ng-repeat="products in bag">
            <div ng-repeat="picture in bag.pictures">
                <img u="image" src="{{picture.url}}"></img>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In your Javascript file

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function ($scope, $timeout) {
    $timeout(function () {
        jssor_slider1_starter('slider1_container');
    });
}]);
```

Comment: From this error `NetworkError: 404 Not Found`, seems your model `bag.pictures` is not correctly set. Better to put it on JSFiddle.

Comment: If I put the repeated images outside the slider, all of them are rendered correctly beneath each other. So I assume the reference is corrent in general, but jssor has problems at rendering time (tries to render `src={{picture.url}}` **before** angularjs is rendered, and thus the image divs are not already replaced.

Comment: Because `ng-repeat` will delay the rendering to some later time. Please make it alive on JSFiddle or Plunker. That would be helpful.

Comment: I cannot make it live as the json data retrieved for `products` and images url come from an internal network webservice...

Comment: Sorry, I could not get it working on plunkr (also because I cannot upload static resources needed for the slider). But maybe you get the idea: http://plnkr.co/edit/IYKXWrtc9xmSKngbzps1

Comment: I'm a step further: angularjs requires to use `ng-src` in image take: `<img ng-src=.." />`. Now the 404 error is resolved. I can also see the slider itself using your suggested js `$timeout`. BUT: There are just two images: the initial and a blank one. Also, the images are not cropped. This is strange because in the `DOM` I can see all images. Just `jssor` does not seem to process them...